# Deploying Laravel workbench projects through composer

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I've created several private repos that I'm working on through Laravel 4.2's workbench feature.

How do I get composer to also install/update all the git submodules in the workbench dir on the production server when it updates the vendor dir for the main project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you force composer to do that ?.

I guess you have following project pattern.

`Project - A` that have many private repo (submodules). for eg: you can add a blog module(Individual Private repo) as submodule to the `Project - A` .

like

```
git submodule add path_to_private_repo_for_blog  workbench/Vendor_folder/blog.
```

Once you created all the individual repo as submodule like above. then you can get update using following command.

```
git pull && git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

so simply you can update and deploy the `Project -A` with following command.

```
git pull && git submodule foreach git pull origin master && git add -A && git commit -m 'updated pakages' && git push && envoy run update
```

hope it make sense..

Comment: Would you be able to answer this question as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30224444/pulling-git-submodules-using-ssh-key-instead-of-password