# Pulling git submodules using SSH key instead of password

Tags: git

I have 5 entries like this in .gitmodules:

```
[submodule "workbench/myuser/my-package"]
    path = workbench/myuser/my-package
    url = git@bitbucket.org:myuser/my-package.git
```

Everytime I do `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` to update them all, I'm asked for a password for each one. How do I make git use my SSH key to access the submodule repos instead of using a password?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes, Its quite simple, while you adding your submodule you have to choose SSH key link (means no https) in bitbucket or gitAcc its there. just before the link.

So once your machine SSH key is linked in the Bitbucket/GitAcc. The thing you made correctly then also it ask for password each time. you have to check the main project checkout with SSH url or not.

Another possibility is the individual repo you don't have SSH access.

All these are correct you are good to go. 
It should work.

Comment: The SSH URL for the submodules is "git@bitbucket.org:myuser/my-package.git" but that is still asking for a password.

Comment: will you able to checkout that individual repo and push to it , without asking password ? then you can make sure it works here too, other wise you don't have SSH access to that repo.

Comment: As it turns out, although I had SSH access set in the submodule list file for the parent repo, I did not have SSH set in each of the configs for the submodules themselves. Changing that and configuring ssh-agent resolved the password issue. Thanks for your help!